# spark sbt with graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am new to scala and sbt thing, so I am not sure why I am getting the error.

The following is my build.sbt

```
name := "graphx-example"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.4" % "test",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "1.2.1" % "provided"

)
```

But I get the following error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is version mismatch. You use:

- Spark 2.2
- GraphX 1.2.

All Spark components should have the same major version.

Furthermore your `provided` seems wrong. Typically you should have all Spark libs as provided, or none.